# How too stop IK to FK switch animating

Tags: animation, rigging, keyframes

[image]

My ik to fk switch is moving, there are no frames i know of which is switching them

Comment: There seem to be keyframes on them indicated by the green hilights. Can you right-click on them and select 'Remove from Keying Set'?

Comment: @JohnEason it didnt see too do anything it still flashes green and yellow

Comment: In that case we'll need to look at your Blend file to see what's going on. https://pasteall.org/blend/ and follow the instructions.

Comment: Try right-click, *Delete Keyframes* and then again *Clear Keyframes*. It should be grey then.

Comment: @Blunder i did that and it works but now how do i make so when i switch too that animation it uses Fk instead of Ik, which on another animation is being used

Comment: Is that a rigify-generated rig?

Comment: @MartyFouts yes sir

Comment: If you always want to use one mode or the other, clear all of the keyframes as @Blunder said, then go to frame 0, set the FK/IK switch to the value you want and add a keyframe for the switch.  If you then want to switch modes, go the frame 1 before you where you want the switch, and add a keyframe form the switch.  Go to the next frame (the one you want),  hit the appropriate copy (IK->FK or FK->IK) so that the IK and FK bones now match, do the switch, and then keyframe it.  You'll probably also have to keyframe both bone chains at frame 0 and at each switch point.